# Use another class' methods without decorators and inheritance

Tags: python, oop, magic-methods, getattr

I have a class, which have several methods of its own, not shown here for simplicity:

```py
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, arg: str):
    self.bar = arg
```

Let's say, aside from its own methods, I want `Foo`'s instances to use `str`'s methods in its `bar` property's (assured to be a string) stead. This is possible with the `__getattr__` dunder method:

```py
class Foo:
  def __getattr__(self, item):
    return getattr(self.foo, item)
```

The call's result should be `.bar`'s new value. However, since Python strings are immutable, a string resulted from a method call (say, `str.strip()`) will need to be re-assigned, which doesn't look very nice. Also, an `if` is needed in case that call doesn't return a string:

```py
result = instance_of_Foo.strip()
if isinstance(result, str):
  instance_of_Foo.bar = result
else:
  ...
```

I solved this problem with a decorator:

```py
def decorator(function, *, self):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        
    if isinstance(result, str):
      self.bar = result
    else:
      return result

  return wrapper

class Foo:
  def __init__(self, arg: str):
    self.bar = arg

  def __getattr__(self, item):
    method = decorator(getattr(self.bar, item), self = self)
    return method

foo = Foo(' foo ')
print(foo.bar) # ' foo '

foo.strip()
print(foo.bar) # 'foo'
```

...but there surely is a more "Pythonic" way, preferably using dunder methods instead of a decorator, to intercept the call, isn't there? Note that my class cannot substitute a string (Liskov principle violation), so inheritance is out of the question.

Comment: I don't think this can be answered in the abstract. What is the purpose of `Foo`, and what does it need to do that can't be handled by subclassing `str`?

Comment: @chepner It is supposed to represents the `Text` of a `Page`. In the original situation it can inherit `str`'s methods, but how will I intercept a call then? I'm asking this question in general, in case inheritance is not a choice.

Comment: Just because a page contains text doesn't mean it makes sense for the *page* to have an operation that's meant for the text. ["Explicit is better than implicit".](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) If you want to strip whitespace from the text, then use `page.text.strip()`, not `page.strip()`.

Comment: No, `Text` has a property named `content` (I did write it in PascalCase) and it would make more sense to do `text.strip()` instead of `text.content = text.content.strip()`, wouldn't it?

Comment: That's a much bigger change in semantics than can or should be handled by simply delegating the method call to an attribute. The fact that you are calling both operations `strip` is little more than a coincidence in naming.

Comment: Because it's not a coincidence. I'm deliberately intercepting all calls to `str`'s methods and assign the result to the property if it's a string, or returns it if not. Re-delaring tens of attributes just to delegate them sounds inelegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

You (or I) can use a wrapper and cache the `__getattr__` dunder method. However, [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75791915/21305238) should be preferred as it can handle an arbitrary given function and is better designed.

```py
from functools import cache

class Foo:
  def __init__(self, arg: str):
    self.bar = arg

  @cache
  def __getattr__(self, item):
    method = getattr(self.bar, item)
        
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      result = method(*args, **kwargs)
            
      if isinstance(result, str):
        self.bar = result
      else:
        return result
    
    print(f'{id(wrapper)}')
    
    return wrapper
```

Try it:

```py
foo = Foo(' foo ')
print(foo.bar)  # ' foo '

foo.strip()     # id(wrapper) = 2345672443040
print(foo.bar)  # 'foo'

foo.center(7)   # id(wrapper) = 2345681396384
print(foo.bar)  # '  foo  '

foo.center(9)   # Nothing, cached.
print(foo.bar)  # '   foo   '

foo.strip(' ')  # With an argument, also nothing.
print(foo.bar)  # 'foo'
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't just delegating calls to string methods to an underlying string attribute. You are trying to modify the attribute using the result of the string method call. This itself should be handled by a separate method on your wrapper class.

```
from operator import methodcaller

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, some_text):
        self.bar = some_text

    def update_with(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bar = methodcaller(method, *args, **kwargs)(self.bar)


f = Foo("--hello, world--")
# not f.strip('-'), but
f.update_with('strip', '-')
```

Passing a string, rather than an explicit unbound method, works better in handling possible subclasses of `str`. Compare

```
class Foo:
    ...

    def update_with_unbound_method(self, f, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bar = f(self.bar, *args, **kwargs)


f = Foo(MyStrSubclass("--hello, world--"))

# The following might work differently, and require you to know
# what subclass was used to create f to get the correct call.
f.update_with_unbound_method(str.strip, '-')
f.update_with_unbound_method(MyStrSubclass.strip, '-')
```